# Unable to scroll RecyclerView on some fragments on one device

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I have some strange problem, just noticed it now. I have `ViewPager` with 3 fragments using same layout with `RecyclerView` and it works on 4 devices I tested (Nexus 7, HTC 816, HTC 610 and Xperia SP), but it doesn't work with Nexus S.

Scrolling only works normally on last fragment, but on first two you need to start scrolling from very top or bottom of list.

This is the layout used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_dictionary"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@color/myLightPrimaryColor"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

And only difference in code is here:

(this one doesn't work)

```
@Override
    protected void updateDisplay() {
        // get new word count
        newWords    = SharedPrefsHelper.getDictionaryCountDifference(getActivity());
        adapter     = new DictionaryAdapter(listDictionary, getActivity(), newWords);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

(this one does)

```
@Override
    protected void updateDisplay() {
        // sort words by best voted (upvote - downvote)
        Comparator<Dictionary> comparator = new Comparator<Dictionary>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Dictionary lhs, Dictionary rhs) {
                int leftLike, leftDislike, rightLike, rightDislike;

                if (lhs.getLikes() == null)
                    leftLike = 0;
                else leftLike = Integer.parseInt(lhs.getLikes());

                if (lhs.getDislikes() == null)
                    leftDislike = 0;
                else leftDislike = Integer.parseInt(lhs.getDislikes());

                if (rhs.getLikes() == null)
                    rightLike = 0;
                else rightLike = Integer.parseInt(rhs.getLikes());

                if (rhs.getDislikes() == null)
                    rightDislike = 0;
                else rightDislike = Integer.parseInt(rhs.getDislikes());

                return (rightLike - rightDislike) - (leftLike - leftDislike);
            }
        };

        Collections.sort(listDictionary, comparator);
        adapter = new DictionaryAdapter(listDictionary, getActivity());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I don't see why that part of code would make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I wasn't watching on right place to fix this.. `ViewPager` animation was causing problem, this one to be specific:

```
pager.setPageTransformer(true, new DepthPageTransformer());
```

That is animation from https://github.com/ToxicBakery/ViewPagerTransforms , but the other ones work (didn't test all of them). And it didn't work on any 4.1 Android device, tried one more and emulator.